# Using a Recursive CTE function to check every row against every other row

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm trying to update a table such that I mark any entries that have duplicate name entries. I do a little processing to remove some common prefixes and suffixes and can then run two names against each other with a fuzzy matching CLR. I have written it as a nested cursor, and it currently takes something like 4 hours to run through all the records as I have to check every row against every other row. I've read that using recursive CTE could improve performance significantly, however I'm a bit of a SQL noob and can't quite get it to work. I think I need to nest one recursive CTE into another, but not sure how.

At the moment I have something like:

```
;WITH AllOrgs (CompanyId, CompanyRoleId, Name, Recognized, Level)
AS 
(
    SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CompanyRoleId, C.Name, C.Recognized, 1
    FROM Company O
    WHERE DuplicateOfCompanyId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.CompanyId, C.CompanyRoleId, C.Name, R.Recognized, R.Level + 1
    FROM AllOrgs R INNER JOIN Company C
    ON C.CompanyId = R.CompanyId
), 
DuplicateOrgs (CompanyId, CompanyRoleId, Name, Recognized, Level)
As 
(
    SELECT * FROM AllOrgs
    WHERE Recognized = 0 -- Recognized is what the companies are marked when we are satisfied they aren't incorrect
)
UPDATE O
SET C.DuplicateOfCompanyId = A.CompanyId
FROM Company O JOIN DuplicateOrgs A
ON C.CompanyId = A.CompanyID
WHERE master.dbo.fnClrFuzzyMatch(dbo.fnCleanUpCompanyName(A.Name), dbo.fnCleanUpCompanyName(C.Name)) 
    > @CompanyNameMatchValueThreshold
AND A.CompanyRoleID = C.CompanyRoleId -- Role ID must match as duplicates who provide a different function are fine
```

But whenever I try to run it I get a "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." So I'm clearly doing something stupid.

Comment: Recursion isn't a lot better than a cursor. If you want to compare one row with any other row with the same CompanyID, do a self join on CompanyID with a condition that excludes joining one row to itself (eg A.ID<> B.ID) then apply the fuzzy matching function on the results

Comment: For that error message you need OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); This might crash your server if you recurse through a mountain of data

Comment: could you show data example? Are you sure that you can not do the same thing without using cursors or recursive queries at all?

Comment: As a quick data example you have two rows:
ID|RoleID|Name|Recognized|IsduplicateOf
1|1|Quickimart|1|NULL
2|1|Quickimart Ltd|0|NULL
I want to update the Second row as a duplicate of the first row, and I want to be able to do this for every row in the table against every other row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion does not terminate as you are always inserting the anchor values itself with an new level. Example with just a single Row in Company:

AllOrgs after execution of the anchor:
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 1

AllOrgs after recursion 1:
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 1
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 2

AllOrgs after recursion 2:
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 1
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 2
CompanyId1, CompanyRoleId1, name1, Recognized1, 3

...

Try a self join instead:

```
UPDATE C 
SET DuplicateOfCompanyId = Dup.CompanyId
FROM Company C
JOIN Company Dup ON C.CompanyId <> Dup.CompanyID 
    AND master.dbo.fnClrFuzzyMatch(dbo.fnCleanUpCompanyName(C.Name), dbo.fnCleanUpCompanyName(Dup.Name)) > @CompanyNameMatchValueThreshold
    AND C.CompanyRoleID = Dup.CompanyRoleId
```

Note: If there are several duplicates of a company the duplicateOfCompanyId may be arbitrary and not consistent.